# How to run a Python web App for Raspberry Pi locally on Mac OSX

Tags: python, docker

This is a pretty specific question, but perhaps there are ideas in here which are more generally useful. Here goes:

There's an open source media presentation program for Raspberry Pi - allows you to hook up a Pi to a TV and upload images to display on the TV. Repo here: https://github.com/wireload/screenly-ose

Now, I want to fork this repo and make a few custom UI changes for a project that I'm working on, but to do so, I'll have to get it running locally on my environment. And this is where the issue arises.

So the application is a web app written primarily in Python which runs on the Raspberry Pi with Docker.

I can't seem to get a local version of this app running, either with docker or without. Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Run the app directly. The contents of the dockerfile are as follows (lines commented out in the original file have been turned into bold headers by SO auto-formatting, apologies for being hard to read):

-

```
FROM debian:wheezy
MAINTAINER Viktor Petersson <vpetersson@wireload.net>

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install git-core net-tools python-pip python-netifaces python-simplejson python-imaging python-dev sqlite3 && \
    apt-get clean

# Install Python requirements
ADD requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

# Create runtime user
RUN useradd pi

# Install config file and file structure
RUN mkdir -p /home/pi/.screenly /home/pi/screenly /home/pi/screenly_assets
COPY misc/screenly.conf /home/pi/.screenly/screenly.conf
RUN chown -R pi:pi /home/pi

# Copy in code base
COPY . /home/pi/screenly

USER pi
WORKDIR /home/pi/screenly

EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /home/pi/screenly

CMD python server.py
```

So I went through and just installed all the requirements by hand, but when I run `python server.py 8080` there is nothing at localhost:8080

2. Set up docker on OSX with boot2docker and a Linux VM. Then I go into terminal, navigate to the correct folder, and run `docker build -t my_app_name .`

This looks promising at first, but after spending 20 minutes downloading 200MB+ worth of dependencies, it returns an error.

3. Then I tried Kitematic, the GUI app for docker, but this hangs at 99% of the initial setup, every time.

Have been trying to get this application up and running all day. Would appreciate any advice or even being pointed in the correct direction.

Thank you.

Comment: what output did you got when you ran `python server.py 8080` ?

Comment: What error did you get during the docker build process? Did you download or git clone the entire repo? Otherwise your errors were probably missing files and directories from the repo.

Comment: @goncalopp no output when I ran `python server.py 8080`, just went to a new line. @booyaa cloned the repo previously. Will try downloading it and post the docker build errors here.

Comment: are you quite sure the server isn't running, then? Maybe on another port? Did you check `ps` and `netstat`?